# Looking for you at/in the

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> I went looking for you *at/in* McDonald's.

Should it be *at* or *in*? Or both are acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine, although *at* is slightly more vague than *in*, as it suggests the general area of McDonald's, while *in* suggests the *complete interior* of McDonald's, so one might feel *in* is better, especially if the person you're looking for is eating/waiting *inside* McDonald's